# Error in renaming R3 Corda template package

Tags: java, templates, intellij-idea, corda

I have cloned the 'Kotlin CorDapp Template' project. I am trying to rename the package from 'com.template' to 'com.new_name' through IntelliJ. Renaming happens, but I get an error while importing the changes - 'can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key kotlin.gradle.testing.enabled'. Please help.

Comment: Please try clearing cache folders and uninstall/reinstalling kotlin/gradle plugins

Comment: This apparently may be an issue with IDEA. Reher here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/KT-33571?p=IDEA-221487.p-

Answer (score 0):

This looks an error from the IDE.
Somehow it is easy to crash since there are two separate directory requires the same package name.

- contracts
- workflows

A work-around is to right-click on the net.corda.template on both directories and click refactor to rename it properly.